# EKS update config with awscli command "aws eks update-kubeconfig" fails with error "'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

When running following command to update kubernetes config to get connected with EKS cluster then getting this error "'NoneType' object is not iterable"

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region us-east-2 --name <cluster name>
```

Comment: Could you post the output of the command with `--debug` please?

Answer (score 20):

Do you have an existing k8s config? Running

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --region <region> --name <cluster name>`

Generates a ~/.kube/config.

If you already have a ~/.kube/config, there could be a conflict between the file to be generated, and the file that already exists that prevents them from being merged.

If you have a ~/.kube/config file, and you aren't actively using it, running

`rm ~/.kube/config`

and then attempting

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --region us-east-2 --name <cluster name>`

afterwards will likely solve your issue.

If you are using your `~/.kube/config file,` rename it something else so you could use it later, and then run the eks command again.

See a similar issue here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4843

Comment: Thankyou for point this out as there was existing config file that seems to be causing this issue... Once I removed & ran the command then it works fine.... Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 1):

Might be null value set as following so you are getting this error:-

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null
```

run `>  $HOME/.kube/config` will empty exist .kube/config file and then run again following cmd

`aws eks update-kubeconfig --region us-east-2 --name <cluster name>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Run: kubectl config get-contexts.
2. If you see your cluster, run: kubectl config use-context <cluster_name>.
3. If you see your cluster, run: cat ~/.kube/config
4. if you see something like:

apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null

Run: rm ~/.kube/config. It deletes your ~/.kube/config.

5. Then run: aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster_name> --region <cluster_region>. It creates ~/.kube/config.
6. Run kubectl config current-context to see your context. End.

!!! Be sure you are in the right account: aws sts get-caller-identity.